# Bold font in user interface of LibreOffice

Tags: 10.04, libreoffice, fonts

I just had a new installation of LibreOffice from apt-get and it seems that all the fonts in the user interface (text in menus, text in dialogs etc...) appears to be bold.

[image]

It creates an uncomfortable feeling (at least to me), therefore I want to ask is there any way to make the font to become normal (not bold) ?

Also, as you can see, the checkbox of "Use system font.." is checked, but the fonts actually look weird to me. Other applications, e.g. Firefox, gedit ... do not have fonts look like that. Is there a problem somewhere else in options ?

My system is Ubuntu 10.04. I just recently removed OOo to install LO.

Also, here is the screenshot of my fonts settings:

[image]

So what's the problem with my setup ?